# PHP SVN Checkout via HTTPS

Tags: php, svn, https

I want to create an SVN checkout PHP script. All you need is to call a function and pass two parameters: the SVN URL and the output path.

My problem is, that our SVN server can only be accessed via https. But through https, the function doesn't work. Normally the function should return a boolean, but I just get nothing. My first thought was, that I have no permission to write into the output path folder, but I changed the permission to 777 (temporarily). Still doesn't work. I also tried to get some files from another SVN trunk. Behold, this is working. I get the files. Any idea how to get this to work?

Aah, and yes, I set the svn trunk permission to read-write for everyone.

Here's is my code:

```
<?php
    $result = svn_checkout('https://{LINK_TO_SVN_TRUNK}', dirname(__FILE__) . '/tmp');
    echo "Result: ".$result;
?>
```

Comment: did you enable error reporting? Try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', true);` on top of your script

Comment: In addition, you may need php's openssl extension installed

Comment: @periklis I get this error: `Server certificate verification failed: certificate has expired, certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted` - How to handle that. Can I pass username and pw, cause i have a user which will have access to the trunk.

Comment: This means that the SSL certificate of the svn server is not trusted from your own server. You need to install the SSL certificate inside your web server. Do a quick google search on how to do this and post back if you need further assistance

Comment: Is there any other possibility, cause i changed my code. I used the function `svn_auth_set_paramter`and set some paras like username and password. Now i have another error: `Warning: svn_log(): svn error(s) occured 175002 (RA layer request failed) OPTIONS of 'https://{URL_TO_SVN_TRUNK}': 200 OK (https://MAIN_URL}) in /{LOCAL_PATH_TO_PHP_SCRIPT} on line 10 bool(false)`

Comment: @periklis I tried this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.svn-auth-set-parameter.php I accepted the cert on the server, but i get still the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting this, but I posted an answer with some code I have used in the past that successfully connected to an svn repo under https

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have used successfully in the past:

```
svn_auth_set_parameter(PHP_SVN_AUTH_PARAM_IGNORE_SSL_VERIFY_ERRORS, true);
svn_auth_set_parameter(SVN_AUTH_PARAM_DEFAULT_USERNAME, "username");
svn_auth_set_parameter(SVN_AUTH_PARAM_DEFAULT_PASSWORD, "password");
$changeLog = svn_log($path, $start_revision, $end_revision);
```

Comment: I used the same. `PHP_SVN_AUTH_PARAM_IGNORE_SLL_VERIFY_ERRORS`set to true and passed Username as well as the password.

Comment: How about the solution suggested in the first comment in `http://php.net/manual/en/function.svn-auth-set-parameter.php`?

Comment: Yap, did that. Connected to the server and trusted the certificate. Also updated the code as shown in the comment. Just changed the urls, username and password.

Comment: which version of php's svn are you using?

Comment: Version 1.6.2 - and ouh.. it sais, thats only will work for svn client libraries below 1.6..

Comment: I'm not sure how I can help further... but please do post the solution when you figure it out

Answer (score -1):

Please confirm if the extension is enabled. php.ini should consist of `extension=svn.so` or php.d folder should consist svn.ini with the line `extension=svn.so`. You can check for extension in `phpinfo();`

Comment: Use missunderstood me. It works with http, but without https.

Comment: Okay. And what is the output of `var_dump(svn_checkout('https://{LINK_TO_SVN_TRUNK}', dirname(__FILE__) . '/tmp'));`

Comment: "Server certificate verification failed: certificate has expired, certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted" hmm, i have a username and pw for access to this svn trunk via browser. how to code it with authentication?

Comment: @Jigar downvoting because you didn't actually read the OP's question before posting

Comment: @periklis : Okay
@Sylnois : you can refer `svn_auth_set_parameter ( string $key , string $value )` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.svn-auth-set-parameter.php, here is the pre defined constants list ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/svn.constants.php#svn.constants.auth ) this is experimental now. Though you can try. :)